# Потоки в клиент-серверном взаимодействии?

Tags: c, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер, веб-служба, сокеты

При запросе на сервер, для каждого запроса создается свой сокет? Тогда сервер мог бы обслуживать столько запросов сколько позволяют ресурсы, но логика приложения может выполняться только в одном потоке из за этого логично, для каждого запроса создавать поток?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 и HTTP/2 позволяют отправлять несколько запросов в пределах одного сокета. А при чём тут потоки, я не понял, можете создавать или не создавать их как удобно для вашего приложения

Comment: То есть сервер может принимать сколько угодно запросов, на каждый запрос будет создан сокет(понял что может быть и к одному сокету несколько запросов) а уже как их обрабатывать, зависит от логики приложения, хочешь в одном потоке, другие запросы будут ждать, хочешь создавай для каждого новый поток, так?

Comment: `для каждого запроса создается свой сокет` - да, и каждый из них в фоне накапливает свои входящие данные от своего клиента. `... из за этого логично, для каждого запроса создавать поток` - или, как альтернативный вариант, обегать все сокеты одним потоком по кругу, преобразуя каждый запрос клиента в асинхронную команду чтения/записи для операционной системы;  вычислительные же запросы раскидывать по рабочим потокам, выделенным не под подключения, а под задачи. Например, один поток генерирует страницы, другой генерирует картинки. Буду рад, если кто-то другой распишет это более развёрнуто.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> Буду рад, если кто-то другой распишет это более развёрнуто.

Более развёрнуто это расписано в книге

"Сети TCP/IP, том 3. Разработка приложений типа клиент/сервер для Linux/POSIX". Вильямс 2002.

Глава 11. Параллельные серверы с установлением логического соединения (TCP) - стр 161.